# xamarin forms ios release build hangs

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin.forms, build, freeze

I'm running VS 2019 from my windows machine and connecting to my Mac through VS.
I can successfully connect to the Mac without issue.
The problem arises when I perform a release build, the build hangs on "compiling to native". When I cancel the build the following output is displayed on the output console:

5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning : The client build16408Alpha has been disconnected while waiting a post response to topic xvs/Build/16.3.0.278/execute-task/UI.iOS/1951504002fMTouch
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning : An error occurred on the underlying client while executing an operation. Details: The client  has been disconnected while trying to perform the unsubscribe to topics: xma/last-will
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning : The client build16408Alpha has been disconnected while waiting a post response to topic xvs/Build/16.3.0.278/execute-task/UI.iOS/1951504002fMTouch
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning :    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.d__23`2.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\445\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 175
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning : System.Net.Mqtt.MqttClientException: The client  has been disconnected while trying to perform the unsubscribe to topics: xma/last-will
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning :    at System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl.<UnsubscribeAsync>d__33.MoveNext() in E:\A\_work\2653\s\src\Client\Sdk\MqttClientImpl.cs:line 302
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning : --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning :    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning :    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): warning :    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.TopicObservable`1.<b__5_0>d.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\445\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\TopicObservable.cs:line 32
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(842,3): error : The client build16408Alpha has been disconnected while waiting a post response to topic xvs/Build/16.3.0.278/execute-task/UI.iOS/1951504002fMTouch

It seems like the connection to the Mac drops off midway when performing a release build.
All my software is up to date. I can also run the iOS simulators on the Mac in debug mode.
Any help would be much appreciated.. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi, first you need to keep the version of vs and xcode be the latest ,then you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows#update-the-release-build-configuration) to check where problem is .And make sure that `iOS Bundle Signing` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Before releasing Build ,keep visual stuido and xcode be the latest version.

And you shoud [Selecting a Distribution Profile in a Xamarin.iOS Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/?tabs=windows#selecting-a-distribution-profile-in-a-xamarinios-project).

In Visual Studio, do the following:

- Right-click the project name in the **Solution Explorer** and select **Properties** to open it for edit.
- Select **iOS Bundle Signing** and **Release** | **iPhone** from the **Configuration** dropdown:
- In most cases, the **Signing Identity** and the **Provisioning Profile** can be left as their default values of **Automatic** and Visual Studio will choose the correct profile, based on the Bundle Identifier in the `Info.plist`
- If required, select the Signing Identity and Distribution Profile (the one created above) from the drop-downs:

Last, clean project and rebuild again .

Comment: Hello there, I have tried to set the signing identity and provisioning profile to automatic and then performed a clean and rebuild. The issue still remains. Interestingly enough I have tried to build a different solution from a different windows machine and I'm getting the same error message. This would infer that it is the Mac that's causing the problem. I have rolled back XCode and re-installed Xamarin.iOS on the Mac and still no joy.

Comment: @SachK Okey , which version of iOS want to build , have you keep the ide (vs and xcode) be the lastest version ?

Comment: Hi there, I have updated to the latest versions and still experiencing the issue. VS2019 - 16.3.9 & XCode - 11.2.1

Comment: @SachK Got it , if have new ways to check the problem , will share here .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by correcting the iOS build config. Once I did then all I had to do was to wait until the build completed (which was quite a while!).

Comment: Glad to hear that , you need to wait until completed .